# How does x+y = x for non-zero value of y in floating-point arithmetic?

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

So, as the question asks, is we have only normalised floating-point values and normalised results, could you please explain how x + y = x?

I know it all relates to precision, but how can I explain that?

Comment: If `y/x` is tinier in magnitude than machine epsilon, well...

Comment: Can you please continue your explanation?

Comment: I would suggest that you look up what machine epsilon is first, and then we can talk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a floating-point system which keeps track of, say, two decimal digits. If $x=1.0 \times 10^0$ and $y=3.4 \times 10^{-10}$, then the exact value of $x+y$ is $1.00000000034$, which would be represented in your system by the closest floating-point number, which is... Well, what is it?

Comment: please see [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757598/floating-point-operations-do-not-satisfy-the-well-known-laws-for-arithmetic-oper).
How to prove general problem that mentioned in this link?

Comment: @MathMan: I already saw that question, but unfortunately I must say that it was too poorly formatted for me even to bother to figure out exactly what it was about...

Comment: how to prove it in general for any $x,y$ with $|y|<eps\times \beta^{-1}\times |x|$?