# floating-point operations do not satisfy the well-known laws for arithmetic operations

Tags: numerical-methods

Introduction to Numerical Analysis, Stoer, Chapter: Error Analysis, Page 8

if $|y|<\frac{eps}{\beta}|x|$ where $eps = 0.5\times 10^{1-t}$ then $$fl(x+y)=x+^*y=x$$
where $fl(x)=$ normalized floating point number closest to $x$ and $fl(x)=x(1+\epsilon)$ with $|\epsilon|\leq eps$.

**absolute error** is given by
$$|fl(x)-x|\leq 0.5\times \beta^{e(1-t)}
$$.

To prove above equality i have assumed that $\beta=10$ so:
$$|fl(x+y)-x|=|(x+y)(1+\epsilon)-x|\leq|x+y||1+\epsilon|+|x|=|x|(3+2|\epsilon|)\leq 10^{e+1}(3+10^{1-t})
$$

but it is not true! PLEASE Help to prove it :)

Comment: I think you mean $|\textrm{fl}(x+y) - x|$ where you say "absolute error is given by ...". Also, what's $e$  in $\beta^{e(1-t)}$? Should that perhapts be $\epsilon$?

Comment: yes $|\textrm{fl}(x+y) - x|$ and $e$ is exponent an for any $x$ in machine we have $|x|\in [\beta^e,\beta^{e+1})$